# Do you think there is an expression of this sum in terms of known numbers?

Tags: number-theory

The series is the following
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{p_n} \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p_{k}} \right) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2} \right) + \dots
$$
where $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime number.

It converges very slowly to a limit which is between $0.96$ and $1$ (in fact I guess it is not greater than $0.97$).

If you think there is no hope of expressing the result in an "analytic" form, do you have any suggestions to prove it to be strictly smaller than $1$?

Comment: Where did that come from?

Comment: the prime number theorem tells us that $p_n \sim n \ln n$ and $\sum_{p \le x} \frac{1}{p} \sim\sum_{n \le x} \frac{1}{n \ln n} \sim \ln \ln x$ so with $\ln \prod_{p \le x} (1-\frac{1}{p}) =-\sum_{p \le x} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k p^k} \sim c - \sum_{p \le x} \frac{1}{p} \sim c - \ln \ln x$ we have $\prod_{p \le x} (1-\frac{1}{p}) \sim C e^{-\ln \ln x} \sim \frac{C}{\ln x}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{p_n} \prod_{p < p_n} (1-\frac{1}{p}) \sim \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n \ln n} \prod_{p < n \ln n} (1-\frac{1}{p}) \sim\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{C}{n \ln^2 n}$ so the convergence is very slow

Comment: @Peter: how did you sum so many terms in so little time?

Comment: It is well known that $(1-1/2)(1-1/3)...(1-1/p)$~$\frac{e^{-\gamma}}{log(p)}$, but I do not know whether we have $(1-1/2)(1-1/3)...(1-1/p)<\frac{e^{-\gamma}}{log(p)}$ for all $p$. This would give a good upper bound for the tail of the sequence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function, evaluated up to term $t$ is
$$ \begin{array} {rll}  f(t)&=&\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^t \frac{1}{p_n} \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p_{k}} \right) \\
\displaystyle  \lim_{t \to \infty} f(t) &=& ??? 
\end{array}  $$
where $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime number.

I call $$P(m) = \prod_{k=1}^m(1-1/p_k) \qquad P(0)=1 $$
With this I rewrite your expression to arrive at a telescoping sum:
$$ { \begin{array} {rll}
f(t) &=&\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^t (1-(1-\frac{1}{p_n})) P(n-1)  \\
&=& \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^t 1 \cdot P(n-1)- \sum_{n=1}^t (1-\frac{1}{p_n}) P(n-1) \\
&=& \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^t P(n-1)- \sum_{n=1}^t P(n)\\
&=& \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{t-1} P(n)- \sum_{n=1}^t P(n)\\
&=&  P(0)- P(t) \\
&=&  1 - P(t)\\
 \end{array} }
$$
Now $\displaystyle \lim_{t \to \infty} P(t) = 1 / \zeta(1) = 0 $ so your result should become
$$ \displaystyle \lim_{t \to \infty} f(t) = 1 $$

Comment: Very elegant indeed!

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER

It is just a calculation with PARI/GP to get a feeling how slowly this sequence converges :

```
? z=2;s=1.0/2;p=1.0;for(n=2,10^5,p=p*(1-1/z);s=s+p/nextprime(z+1);z=nextprime(z+
1));print(s)
0.9601193430638145711397847250
? z=2;s=1.0/2;p=1.0;for(n=2,10^6,p=p*(1-1/z);s=s+p/nextprime(z+1);z=nextprime(z+
1));print(s)
0.9660863434713390746794384459
? z=2;s=1.0/2;p=1.0;for(n=2,10^7,p=p*(1-1/z);s=s+p/nextprime(z+1);z=nextprime(z+
1));print(s)
0.9704578534037109859659244473
? z=2;s=1.0/2;p=1.0;for(n=2,10^8,p=p*(1-1/z);s=s+p/nextprime(z+1);z=nextprime(z+
1));print(s)
0.9738067735684381538224687762
?
```

The trick I used : I multiplied the current product with (1-1/ current prime) and divided by the next prime to get the next term and summed them up.

Comparing with the direct method (computing the sum)

```
? sum(n=1,1000,1/prime(n)*prod(k=1,n-1,1-1/prime(k)))*1.0
%53 = 0.9375334070533336900160682021
? z=2;s=1.0/2;p=1.0;for(n=2,1000,p=p*(1-1/z);s=s+p/nextprime(z+1);z=nextprime(z+
1));print(s)
0.9375334070533336900160681959
?
```

reveals that the results virtually coincide. I think the difference is due to some numerical issue.

Comment: It does converge as $\sum_n \frac{1}{n \ln^2 n }$, I showed it above

Comment: I can compute an upper bound from $\frac{x}{2 \ln x}< \pi(x)< \frac{2x}{\ln x}$ but it will be of the form $\sum_{n=N}^\infty \ldots < B \int_N^\infty \frac{dx}{x \ln^2 x} = B \int_{\ln N}^\infty \frac{dt}{t^2 } = \frac{B}{3 \ln N} $

Comment: What I want to say : If we approximate every product, can we be sure that the convergence of the approximated sum shows the convergence of the original sum ? What about the $B$ in your upper bound ? Is $B$ bounded ?

Comment: yes, we are sure of the convergence because we really have $p_n\prod_{p < p_n} (1-1/p) < \frac{B}{n\ln^2 n}$ for some $B$ that should be $< 4$

Comment: You're right, the difference must be by numerical issues. I've the default-precision to 200 internal decimal digits and your programs give both the value  0.93753340705333369001606820210208086755827727186109
when printed to 50 digits.

Comment: My implementation help to find empirically the replacement of the costly computation of the sum by the simple product term only. See this: $$ \small { prd(n)=prod(k=1,n,1-1/prime(k)) \\
suprd(n)=sum(k=1,n,1/prime(k)*prd(k-1)) \\
[suprd(2),1-prd(2)]   (= [2/3, 2/3]) )\\ 
[suprd(3),1-prd(3)]  (= [11/15, 11/15] )\\ 
[suprd(4),1-prd(4)]  (=  [27/35, 27/35] )\\
[suprd(10),1-prd(10)]  (= [2358365/2800733, 2358365/2800733] )\\ }
$$