# What is the solution to prime sum problem, is it a surreal number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, surreal-numbers

What is the solution to prime sum problem, is it a surreal number ?
If not, then what is it ?

---

Let there be a set of natural numbers :
$$1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, \dots$$

Half of this set are divided by firs prime :
$$
\frac{1}{2}
$$

Considering unique divisions by second prime :
$$
\frac{1}{2} + \left(\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{2\cdot3}\right)
$$

Considering unique division by third prime :
$$
\frac{1}{2} + \left(\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{2\cdot3}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{2\cdot5}-\frac{1}{3\cdot5}+\frac{1}{2\cdot3\cdot5}\right)
$$

And so on
$$
\dots
$$

---

This problem can be written as :
$$
S = \frac{1}{p_1}\!+\!\frac{1}{p_2}\left(1\!-\!\frac{1}{p_1}\right)\!+\! \frac{1}{3}\left(1\!-\!\frac{1}{p_2}\right)\left(1\!-\!\frac{1}{p_1}\right)\!+\!\ldots\!=\!1\!-\!\delta
$$

This sum follows to $1$ but it never be, because we never take in account $1$ from this set.
What value then $\delta$ have, is it infinitely small ?

Comment: Compare e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4610336/42969

Comment: Avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication. That's a common practice in programming, not in Mathematics where it has other meanings. Use `\cdot` ($\cdot$) or `\times` ($\times$)

Comment: Why isn’t it the case that $\delta=0$?

Comment: I think you might mean "irrational", rather than "surreal". Surreal numbers are from a completely different part of maths.

Comment: @PatrickStevens No reason for "irrational". I'd rather guess he meant [some sort of infinitesimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal#Number_systems_that_include_infinitesimals).

Comment: $\frac{1}{p_3}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{p_1}\right)$ gives $\frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{2 \cdot 5} - \frac{1}{3 \cdot 5} + \frac{1}{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5}$, but your line above has $\cdots - \frac{1}{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5}$. Which sign do you want on a reciprocal product of three primes?

Comment: This answer your question: [Do you think there is an expression of this sum in terms of known numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860246/do-you-think-there-is-an-expression-of-this-sum-in-terms-of-known-numbers) ($\delta=0$).